# Re-Enable RDP Via Remote Registry

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, windows-registry

I'm having a problem where for some reason, Remote Desktop (RDP) continually gets disabled on a Win2003 server.  Our networking team is not doing this, so as far as I know it is not a security script that is running, etc.

In any case, I am able however to access the remote registry, since I am an administrator on the site.  My question is, what registry key do I need to change in order to re-enable remote desktop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Server 2003 the key is:

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal
>   Server\fDenyTSConnections

change it from 1 to 0.

Comment: Thanks - though note that a reboot does not appear necessary.  Worked as soon as I changed the key.

Comment: edited accordingly

Comment: I'd add this setting to Group Policy Preferences if you want it enabled on all your servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which key it is, but you could use [IntelliAdmin Remote Desktop Enabler](https://www.intelliadmin.com/blog/2006/06/remotely-enable-remote-desktop.html).

You can run RegMon at the same time to find out which key it changes.

Comment: downvote? dang... oh well, I really like that tool... :D